# How to combine columns and change timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[image: CSV file]

I want to merge columns `DATE` and `TIME` into one "date&time" column and change timezone from Brussel to New York. I tried:

```
import pandas as pd


#df = pd.read_csv('ES.csv', parse_dates=True)
df = pd.read_csv('ES.csv')
df_small = df[-10:]
df_small['dateandtime'] = df['DATE'].astype(str) + df['TIME'].astype(str)
df_small.info()
df_small.to_frame(name='new')
df_small.to_frame(name='new').to_csv('new.csv')
```

Errors and warnings:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

df_small.to_frame(name='new')
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'
```

If you get it working you can have the full CSV file which I think is worth 500$-3000$ (10 years of financial 1 minute interval S&P500 futures data).

Comment: "... *worth 500$-3000$* ..." Live updates in that resolution on a monthly subscription base may be. Anything older than 30 minutes has no practical value (and is publicly available for free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .cat to combine columns .pop() to remove old columns finally .to_localize() as Brussels tz and .tz_convert() to New York tz. Converting DatetimeIndex to str will take much more time than leaving it as datetime:

```
df_small["dateandtime"] = (pd
                           .to_datetime(df_small.pop("DATE").str.cat(df_small.pop("TIME"), sep=" "))
                           .dt.tz_localize("Europe/Brussels")
                           .dt.tz_convert("America/New_York")
                           )
df_small = df_small.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_small.pop("dateandtime")))
df_small.index = df_small.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Output:

```
                    OPEN    HIGH     LOW   CLOSE  VOLUME
dateandtime                                             
2010-01-03 18:01 1113.75 1114.75 1113.25 1114.25    2185
2010-01-03 18:02 1114.25 1115.25 1114.25 1114.75     437
2010-01-03 18:03 1114.75 1114.75 1114.25  1114.5     596
2010-01-03 18:04 1114.25 1114.75 1114.25  1114.5     131
2010-01-03 18:05  1114.5  1114.5 1114.25 1114.25     166
```

Comment: i cant use .dt.strftime [1] because the CSV file seems to be to big for that and [2] because i need datetimeindex to use a specific module i want to use which needs that [mplfinance] do you want to have the full-csv file? you help me a lot.

Comment: yeah host it somewhere